# Georeferencing an aerial image based on satellite imagery

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, landsat, aerial-photography

As part of a bigger project I need to georeference an aerial image based on a landsat image downloaded form usgs. I use qgis. can I somehow place the layers on top of each other and mark certain points to apply the references of the downloaded image to the aerial photage?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, under Raster > Georeferencer

Comment: Much thanks, I am just trying to work it out in Georeferencer. I just can't find the option to place the layers on top of each other, increase transparency for the upper one and match them exactly. The area I am interested in is a river and only some meters wide, so accuracy is a big issue.

Comment: Guides: http://geo.nls.uk/urbhist/guides_georeferencingqgis.html http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/tutorial-georeferencing-topo-sheets.html http://glaikit.org/2011/03/27/image-georeferencing-with-qgis/ http://mapeoamano.org/en/manuals/how-to-georeference-a-satellite-image-in-qgis AND finally a youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZUx-7wj0-U